# Keep getting missing module error when trying to do npm start

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I keep getting the following error:

```
> kb-ui@0.0.1 start C:\Users\Tayeb\Desktop\F2f\bloomkonnect-fe
> webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js --progress --watch

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'json-parse-better-errors'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Tayeb\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js
- C:\Users\Tayeb\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js
- C:\Users\Tayeb\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Tayeb\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:7:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Tayeb\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\webpack\\lib\\Compiler.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Tayeb\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\webpack\\lib\\webpack.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Tayeb\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\webpack-dev-server\\bin\\webpack-dev-server.js'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! kb-ui@0.0.1 start: `webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js --progress --watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the kb-ui@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Tayeb\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-06-23T17_23_33_473Z-debug.log
```

I have tried doing the following:
remove the node modules folder and run npm install
remove the node modules and package lock json and do npm install
re install node.js
delete the clone the repository again

I dont get what is wrong. When I look inside the node modules folder the module it is saying is missing is there. This is driving me nuts.

Comment: try - npm install -f

Comment: @sathishk2030 didnt work same error